# Override base CSS in react-select component

Tags: react-select

I am trying to override the `.Select-control` css component in react-select.

I want to set a custom height (the default is 36px) so it will look more closely to my other input fields

I have tried to add my own `className` prop as suggested in the [docs](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#custom-classnames) however it does not seem to work and just pushes everything down (which makes sense since it's the wrapper for the component)

Is it possible to override the component itself?

Answer (score 1):

I just started working with react-select and ended up overriding the components to bring the elements in line but also had success with passing in my own classes.

```
    .Select-control {
      height: 32px
    }
```

I noticed that some of the css selectors can be pretty specific so referencing the css file helped to make sure I overrode the included styles. If you're using ES6 syntax I think you need to import your css after importing the react-select css in order to override.

Hope that helps